# How do I stop Google notification of sport scores on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

On my iPhone's notification center, there is a section showing Google notifications. I get notified of baseball and now football scores. How to stop these specific notifications?

Comment: In general Notifications can be disabled in Settings. If you have problems finding the app causing these notifications please add a screenshot showing the notification.

Comment: why would you want to stop baseball scores!  Its September!!  lol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, open **Google** application (it is not Chrome, fully G icon Google apps) that you have installed on your iPhone. Click on **three dots ...(More)** -> **Settings**-> **Notifications** from where you can disable and customize notifications.

Comment: got it. too bad cannot fine tune the notifications in sports category. Tell me about Patriots and Jets, but make it easy to suspend and resume those notifications.